# NoMethodError in Rails::MailersController#preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, preview

I've been receiving this error when I try to preview the my notification emails. Any ideas what might be causing it?

> undefined method `html_part' for # 
>       Did you mean? html_safe?

```
    arel.public_send(method, *args, &block)
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was no html rendering. Have to make sure your previews notify without error or this is the error you get.

Answer (score 4):

I had to remove `.deliver_later` from the preview method.